# "Install for me only" option is grayed out when trying to install programs

Tags: install, permission, user-account

I am running MacOS Ventura on a MacBook Air 2020 (M1). I am running under an admin account, although not the primary account (if there is such a thing). I am trying to install both Microsoft Teams and Citrix. Neither install gives me the option to "Install for me only" as it is grayed out. Is there a way to enable this?
[image]